# Is there a way to index only specific column values in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table of ~13 million rows, and the data in the column I am interested in is distributed like this (http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=aHXjB5FA).

I would like to be able to efficiently find notable values (say, 45 pts and above). Is it possible to create an index only for the rows that have pts >= 45?

If not, will a normal index help? It seems like it would be a waste of disk space, since in this case I am only interested in ~2500 of the 13 million rows. Also, each row has 12 more columns I would like to index similarly (it's a basketball statistics database).

Answer (score 1):

So-called [partial indexes](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/partial-and-filtered-indexes), which add only a subset of table rows into the index, are not supported by MySQL.

Comment: Oh, that's a pity. Would you recommend I go ahead with a normal index instead, or maybe something like a lookup table for "notable" rows?